# Flask, Passing User Entered Data Between Views

Tags: python, html, forms, session, flask

**Problem transferring variables across views** I tried using sessions and could not get the connection to work. Say I have two pages, a `home` and `page2`. I have a flask app that will take user input from the `home` and print out input on `page2`.

---

*For example, if you start my app, you will see this as the home page*:

[image: Home Page]

- This part works fine, I am able to enter a value.

---

*What I want to happen next, is after you click submit, `page2` is generated showing what was just entered*:

[image: page2]

- Whatever string value was entered on `home` should show up in the highlighted portion.

---

I have the following app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

    stringval = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'stringval' in request.form:
        stringval = request.form.get('stringval')
        session["stringvalue_topass"] = stringval
        return render_template('page2.html', stringval = stringval)

    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/page2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page2():
    stringvalue_get = session.get('stringvalue_topass')
    return render_template('page2.html', stringvalue_get = stringvalue_get)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The following home.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<h1>Enter Value </h1>
<div class="main">
    <form class="pure-form" method="POST" action="/page2">
    stringval:<br>
    <input type="text" name="stringval"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" value="Submit">Submit!</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

And the following page2.html

```
<!doctype html>

<h1>You have selected </h1>

<div class="main">
    {% if stringvalue_get %}
        <pre>

    {% print(stringvalue_get) %}
    </pre>
    {% endif %}

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are a few issues here. Firstly, the `action` attribute of your form in `home.html` is set to `"/page2"`. This means that when the form is submitted, the POST request is going to the `/page2` endpoint rather than to the `/home` endpoint, where you have written the code for handling the form submission. We can fix this by just deleting the `action` attribute, as this means the form will post to then endpoint that loaded it - in this case `/home`.

Secondly, Flask sessions cannot be used without setting a secret key to encrypt the session. This can be done by assigning a value to `app.secret_key`, like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b"my_secret_key"
```

Finally, instead of passing the string to the template like so: `render_template('page2.html', stringval = stringval)`, (note also that this should be `stringval_get = stringval`), you can access the `session` object directly from templates already. So, in all, we can change your application code to:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b"my_secret_key"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'stringval' in request.form:
        session["stringvalue_topass"] = request.form.get('stringval')
        return render_template('page2.html')
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/page2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page2():
    return render_template('page2.html')
```

And your templates to:

**home.html:**

```
<!doctype html>

<h1>Enter Value </h1>
<div class="main">
    <form class="pure-form" method="POST">
    stringval:<br>
    <input type="text" name="stringval"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" value="Submit">Submit!</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

**page2.html:**

```
<!doctype html>

<h1>You have selected </h1>

<div class="main">
  {% if 'stringvalue_topass' in session %}
  <pre>

    {% print(session["stringvalue_topass"])  %}
  </pre>
  {% endif %}

</div>

</body>
```